# How to pass parsed arguments to PySerial Api

Tags: python, argparse, pyserial

I collect all the data to parameter the Serial Connexion through User Input.
However Pyserial API doesnt take for exemple the value "EIGHTBITS" directly as parameter but you have to call serial.EIGHTBITS.
Is there a way to over come this ?

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--Port", required=True,
                          help="specify Port Name")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--Baud", type=int,required=True,
                          help="Specify Baud rate")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--timeout", type=float,required=True, 
                          help="Connexion Timeout")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--ByteSize",default="EIGHTBITS",choices=['FIVEBITS','SIXBITS','SEVENBITS','EIGHTBITS'],
                          help="Specify the Data bits number")
ap.add_argument("-s", "--StopBits", default="STOPBITS_ONE",choices=['STOPBITS_ONE','STOPBITS_ONE_POINT_FIVE','STOPBITS_TWO'],
                          help="StopBits Value")
ap.add_argument("-pa", "--parity", default="PARITY_NONE",choices=['PARITY_NONE','PARITY_EVEN','PARITY_ODD','PARITY_MARK','PARITY_SPACE'],
                          help="Set up the Parity Bit")
ap.add_argument("-f", "--FlowControl", type=bool, default=False,
                          help="StopBits Value")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

Port = args["Port"]
BaudRate = args["Baud"]
Timeout = args["timeout"]
ByteSize = args["ByteSize"]
Stop = args["StopBits"]
Parity = args["parity"]
FlowC=args["FlowControl"]

ser=serial.Serial(Port,BaudRate,bytesize=ByteSize,parity=Parity,stopbits=Stop,timeout=Timeout,xonxoff=FlowChart)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getattr to retrieve the value of serial.EIGHTBITS etc from the serial module, by name (string), eg. "EIGHTBITS".

```
Parity = getattr(serial, args["parity"])
```